# Trouble storing PHP variables

Tags: php, html, variables, storage

to start I consider myself in between beginner and intermediate when it comes to PHP.  On my website, I have a textarea that the user can input web code in and when a button is pressed, it sends the code to the page and displays the output.  Here is the link to the page: http://opensourcewebsite.host22.com/editpage.php. Another problem that I am running into is that I want whatever the user enters to stay on the page.

Here is what the code looks like so far:

```
<?php $source_code = $_POST['source-code'}; ?>
...
<editable_area>
<?php echo $source_code ?>
</editable_area>
...
<form action="" method="post">
input class="result" type="submit" name="submit" value="View Result">
<textarea id="source" class="edit_are" name="source-code"></textarea>
```

Currently, when a user inputs code containing  an id/class/name/etc. that has quotes in it, it is like when you do:

```
echo "<div id="Name">"
```

It will add the \" and thus messing up the code.  I need to find a way to store the code so that it will display correctly.  If you try the web page, you will see my issue first hand.

---

When the code is submitted, the textarea grabs the source code of the web page through javascript.  I have discovered that if you leave out the "" in the code, it works as expected. The problem is that when it grabs the source code, there is quotes in it so the code will display them in the textare. This means every time you make a change, you need to take out all of the quotes.

---

Thanks to webbiedave, I fixed the quote problem by using:

```
<?php echo stripslashes($source_code) ?>
```

Now I just need to figure out how to permanently store changes.

Comment: Do you have sick thing called `magic_quotes_gpc` turned on?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php May need to turn this off.

Comment: wow you are just asking for all kinds of trouble with a page like this.  This kind of page is exactly what spammers want to create XXS injection attacks.  make sure that you at least strip `<script>` tags

Comment: I do not have magic_quotes_gpc turned on.  I realize the concern thenetimp, but this is page is not finished yet.  There will be a log-in system and only that user can change the page.  The textarea does not edit outside of the <editable_area> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php echo htmlentities(stripslashes($source_code)) ?>
```

Comment: This worked to an extent, except that it displays the tags on the page instead of reading them. It still didn't fix the quotes.

Comment: have you tried using stripslashes or addslashes to escape the quotes or unescape them?

Comment: I just tried that and it got rid of the slashes but it still displayed the code and not the correct output.  So, I just put stripslashes() and it worked.  Not sure if this is what you meant but it still worked.

Comment: whatever works :D I can't see the output that's why I recommend trying out `stripslashes` or `addslashes`

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on and make sure you [turn them off](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php). Also, you'll want to use [htmlspecialchars](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to escape the special characters. Otherwise, they can just close your `textarea` and wreak other havoc.

```
echo htmlspecialchars($source_code);
```

Comment: I tried changing the code to what you suggested, but when I put in the following code:
    <style type="text/css">
    editable_area {
    padding:10px;
    }
    </style>
It swrites that exactly on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use single quotes instead:
    '<div id="Name">';

Comment: That would normally work but that is not how the variable is stored.
$source_code gets its value by reading what is in the textarea